# Vue JS props gives undefined even declared in parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi im trying to pass the root data to my component, i have 3 type of data. 2 of them works and all of them have the same code, but one of my data gives undefined in my props. here is the sample

```
<my-component v-for="(meat, index) in meats" :key="meat.id" :index="index"></my-component>

---vue script----

Vue.component('my-component', {
     props:['index', 'meat'],
     template: 
     `
     <div>
        <input v-model="meat.kilo"></input>
     </div>
     `,
})


let App = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
   meats: [{
      id:1,
      kilo: 50,
      type: chicken
   ]}.....
```

there, simple as that but when i check my vue dev tool it give me undefined props

[meat undefined props sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKTYJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `v-for` directive does not automatically assign the attribute to the generated component; it just makes that variable available in scope and then lets you do with it what you wish. This includes doing simple operations on it, or giving it as a prop to a child component of the repeating component instead of to the root.

What you actually need to do is this:

```
<my-component v-for="(meat, index) in meats" :meat="meat" :key="meat.id" :index="index"></my-component>
```

It may look repetitive but it's necessary to give you more freedom as to how exactly you want to use the elements of the array.

Comment: thanks dude! i actually forgot to put v-bind:meat = "meat" thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't have `index` and `meat` as props but `meats`. So

Change this:

```
props:('index', 'meat'),
```

To this:

```
props:['meats'], // also to note, it's in array syntax
```

Comment: hi already changed my code. should i use meats props and not meat? as v-for i declared it as 'meat' ?

Comment: vue still give me error 

vendor.js:15819 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'kilo' of undefined"

Comment: It is `meats` not `meat`. The `v-for` is also looking for `meats` not `meat`.

Comment: Now, that's a different error. Because, you have `meat.kilo`.

Comment: if i use meats as props then will i still use 'meat.kilo' or 'meats.kilo'? thanks

Comment: Even `meats.kilo` will not work. Define separate model.